# Javascript countdown won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, countdown

I am trying to make a Javascript countdown for my website, so as a start I wanted to test the best solution. I now have a code, but when I open the website nothing is on there, I think I might have done something wrong when trying to implement Javascript into html?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<head>

    <title>Home Test Countdown</title>

    <script LANGUAGE="Javascript">

    var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

    var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

    var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

    setInterval(function () {

    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

    }, 1000);

</script>

</head>

<body>

<span id="countdown"></span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add type="text/javascript" to script tag

Comment: The script works but there do seem to be some linting errors - http://jsfiddle.net/nz1cb82g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the script in the head, when `var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");` is executed the element is not present in the dom so `countdown` will be null which will result in the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` in line `countdown.innerHTML = '...'`.

One possible solution is to move your code to a window load event handler

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

    var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

    var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

    setInterval(function () {
        var current_date = new Date().getTime();
        var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

        days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
        seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

        hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
        seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

        minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
        seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

        countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, " + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";
    }, 1000);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f05e4njn/)

Another is to move your script to the bottom of the page after `<span id="countdown"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

This code is working you need to add your code after your HTML elements(Add the javascript code before closing the body tag)

or try to add your code in `window.onload` like,

```
window.onload = function(){
   // your timer code goes here
};
```

```js
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2019").getTime();

var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

setInterval(function() {

  var current_date = new Date().getTime();
  var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

  days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

  hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
  seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

  minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
  seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

  countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, " + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";

}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Also you added the tag `jquery` so you can add your code in [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) like,

```
$(function(){
   // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The script needs to be **after** the span countdown object